# Display a visual at a certain position in the browser with JavaScript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible for me to display some sort of visual at a certain position in the browser? Let's say I have these offsets `{ left: 336, top: 378 }` which I am calculating dynamically, and I want to display a small line of some sort (either an `<hr>` or an image, depending on what is possible).

Is this even possible? Ideally I don't want to interfere with the markup at all, I'd rather have some sort of overlay.

Comment: Well you will have to inject something into the page and absolute position it....

Comment: you can create some html item dynamically and set its position using css.

Comment: Research `position: absolute` in CSS.

Comment: Has to be in the document to display it so your ideal of not changing markup is not possible. An append to body though is minimal change

Comment: I think I didn't explain properly what I meant, but thanks for your input guys! I'm on the right track now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish this by using JavaScript to insert an absolutely positioned `hr` into your page:

```js
const loc = { left: 336, top: 378 };
const size = { width: 128, height: 4 };

//Center the element on the location, if desired
const adjustedLoc = {
    left: loc.left - (size.width / 2),
    top: loc.top - (size.height / 2)
}

const floatingLine = document.createElement("hr");
floatingLine.style.position = "absolute";
floatingLine.style.left = adjustedLoc.left + "px";
floatingLine.style.top = adjustedLoc.top + "px";
floatingLine.style.width = size.width + "px";
floatingLine.style.height = size.height + "px";
document.body.appendChild(floatingLine);
```

or swap `hr` for `img`, and specify the `src` property of the element:

```
floatingLine.src = "https://via.placeholder.com/128.png";
```

Be aware that while this isn't changing your source markup (HTML), it is inserting an element into the DOM tree that is generated from your source markup.

Comment: Not exactly what i was looking for, however this put me on the right track! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score -1):

```
#elem{
  position: absolute;
  top-margin:20vh; //vh use for view height
  left-margin:20vw; //vw use for view width
  z-index:1;
}
```

Comment: Make sure to format your code in the editor properly, as this was not readable before I edited it